# which Class or namespace must add for use Class StyleAttrCSSResolver in itextSharp?

Tags: itext

I want that use itextSharp for convert html to pdf.
and I want have a specific style in my pdf.
I want that all pdf files follow a specific CSS class. but I don't know which namespace I must add that complier khnow StyleAttrCSSResolver class? please guide me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That class is [located here](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/b8df805a6f2f487205e51decd8cf8250a3f70efe/src/extras/itextsharp.xmlworker/iTextSharp/tool/xml/css/StyleAttrCSSResolver.cs). Also you need to add a reference to the [xmlworker assembly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp.xmlworker/):

```
PM> Install-Package itextsharp.xmlworker
```

Comment: Anyone else add this and still unable to resolve StyleAttrCSSResolver()? I'm still searching for solution on this.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect recent changes.

Answer (score 0):

Also available in "Friendly Nuget Packages" now http://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp.xmlworker/

```
PM> Install-Package itextsharp.xmlworker
```